# Problem with beamer compilation

Tags: beamer, templates

I am making a presentation with Beamer. Couple days ago I customized the template with some additional stuff such as:

> ```
> \addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt}}
> ```

I had also really simple Tikz figure such as:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Everything worked fine, I had no errors and everything was displayed how I wanted. However, I had some errors when compiling with biblatex (versions error between biber and biblatex). After trying many things without success (such as updates) I deleted miktek (it was the basic version) and installed the complete version. The problem with the bibliography was solved, however I have some new issues. What I costumed does not appear anymore such as the rule in the headline part or the tikzpicture shape.

In addition,  the subsection font size within the table of content in the sidebar decreased (when compared before deleting the miktek version) and the following command neither work

```
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\large}
```

Also, I have many warnings that I did not have before such as:

```
-Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding)
-LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sc' in size <8> not available
```

It looks that the new version is in cause. Is anyone has an idea ?
Thanks a lot

Here the full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,t,aspectratio=43]{beamer} %1610, 149, 54, 43(defaut) and 32. By default, it is to 128mm by 96mm(4:3).
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}% Fontes modernes pour Adobe. Recommandé
\usepackage{multimedia}% pr ajouter des videos
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}
\newlist{arrowlist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[arrowlist]{label=$\Rightarrow$}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,patterns}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,foreground}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize,skip=1pt]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% THEMES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Berkeley}
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip%change size headline default .
\makeatother
\usecolortheme{Dove} 
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
%\usefonttheme{serif}
%\useinnertheme{rectangles} 
%\useoutertheme{sidebar} 
%\setbeamercolor{titre}{bg=blue,fg=white}
%\setbeamercolor{texte}{bg=white,fg=black}


\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
   \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}



\title[Aut]{ \protect{\underline{Presentation:}{\protect{\textit{ name of te presentation}}}}}
\subtitle{\vspace*{+0.4cm} \protect{\underline{to:}} Mr.\\
and Mr.\\}
\author[]{Charles}
\institute{World}
\date{\today}



\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][left]

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt}}
%\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\rule{\paperwidth}{3pt}}{}


\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\large}
%\setbeamerfont{subsubsection in toc}{size=\large}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{first section}
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{first section}
\vspace*{-0.4cm}
\underline{blabla}

\begin{textblock*}{4cm}(2cm,2cm) % {block width} (coords)

\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{7cm}(6.5cm,2.0cm) % {block width} (coords)
Locally introduce:
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> blabl
\item<2-> blabl
\item<3-> blabl
\end{itemize}
\begin{arrowlist}%[leftmargin=1em]
 \item<4-> blabl
\end{arrowlist}

\end{textblock*}



\begin{textblock*}{6cm}(2.0cm,5cm) % {block width} (coords)
\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}

Globally 
\end{textblock*}

\end{frame}


\section{2nd section}
\subsection{2nd section 1st subsection}
\begin{frame}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)circle (10) ;
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{frame}

\subsection{2nd section 2nd subsection}
\begin{frame}
 slide 


\begin{block}{Un bloc normal} 
\end{block}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]

\begin{alertblock}{Bloc alerte} 
\end{alertblock}

\begin{exampleblock}{Un bloc exemple} 
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]

\begin{columns}[c] % choix entre t, b, c

\begin{column}{2cm}
\begin{block}{Bloc n°1}
Texte du bloc n°1.
\end{block}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{block}{Bloc n°2}
Texte du bloc n°2, un peu plus long celui-ci pour voir les alignements.
\end{block}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{2cm}
\begin{block}{Bloc n°3}
Texte du bloc n°3.
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}[label=conclusion]


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I put the full code that you can find above !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Concerning your `tikz` problem**

The circle is invisible, because of changing tikzlayers; try without `\pgfsetlayers{background,foreground}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,t,aspectratio=43]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,patterns}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
%\pgfsetlayers{background,foreground}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle (10);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

**2. The headline problem**

The line is there, it is just white and thus not visible. The colour is white because you use the `dove` colour theme. Quick workaround:

```
\documentclass[12pt,t,aspectratio=43]{beamer} 
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Berkeley}
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip%change size headline default .
\makeatother
\usecolortheme{dove} 
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\color{red}\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**3. Sidebar font size**

`subsection in toc` will modify the fontsize in the table of contents (`\tableofcontents`), not in the sidebar.

```
\documentclass[12pt,t,aspectratio=43]{beamer} 
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Berkeley}

\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\Large}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}{size=\large}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**4. Hyperref warning**

This warning is caused from messing around with the title page layout by using things like `\subtitle{\vspace*{0.4cm} to: Mr. and Mr.}` to add additional space. To remove the warning, use `\subtitle{to: Mr. and Mr.}` and redefine the title page if you want a different layout. Putting formatting instructions in such fields will mess with the pdf meta data.

**5. Superfluous packages**

You don't need

```
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, everything works perfectly.